# How to add title on rectangle object in matlab

Tags: matlab, face-recognition

I used the following code to draw a box on the face

```
rectangle('Position', faceCoord(i,:), ...
       'LineWidth', 2, ...
       'EdgeColor', 'y');
```

Now, I'd like to add a title box on the top of box displaying face name.

I am not able to find an appropriate solution in MATLAB to do this. Can anyone help on it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [annotations](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html).

> `annotation('textbox',[x y w h])` creates an editable text box
>   annotation with its lower left corner at the point x,y, a width w, and
>   a height h, specified in normalized figure units. Specify x, y, w, and
>   h in a single vector.

You will have to experiment some, but you can achieve what you want using the syntax:

```
annotation('textbox', [x y w h], 'String', 'Image title')
```